# To delete lines including the two patterns in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to delete certain lines in my html file,for example between `<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>` and the last occurrence of `</table>` which should include the above two patterns.

Sample Input:

```
</table>
<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>
<table BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=2>
<TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>ID</center></TD> <TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>Find</center></TD> <TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>count</center></TD>
</table>
<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>
<table BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=2>
<TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>ID</center></TD> <TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>Find</center></TD> <TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>count</center></TD>
</table>
<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>
<table BORDER=1 CELLPADDING=2>
<TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>ID</center></TD> <TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>Find</center></TD> <TD BGCOLOR=#5D6D7E><font color=white><center>count</center></TD>
 </table>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Expected Output:

```
</table>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

I tried: `sed -n '/<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>,</table>d/` file_name`, but it's not working.

Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: Use a parser for this!!!

Comment: Please add sample input (valid HTML) and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus: I've included my sample input in the question. The file(html) is just used to send the mail in tabular format. I need to remove the lines starting from the first occurrence of pattern: `<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>` to the last occurrence of pattern: `</table>`.

Comment: some mistakes `/` is the regex delimiter, it must be escaped `/<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>/,/<\/table>/d` also `sed -n` doesn't print output unless explicitly `p`, finally the option to replace in file is `-i`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: Finally!!!!! Thanks :-)

Comment: Nth duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/^<BR\>/,/<\/table>/d' file_name
```

This will delete all the lines including the matching ones and gives the output you want. A few points to note:

- If you only care about deleting certain lines with a certain keyword you don't need to give `sed` the whole line to delete it, only the keyword will be enough.
- If your pattern matches certain characters ( characters that bear some special meaning ) then you will have to escape them by putting a `\` before your keyword.
  Here you needed to escape the `/` of `table` tag because it bears special meaning to `sed`

For reference on `sed` see `man sed`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>/,${H;$!d;x;s/.*<\/table>[^\n]*\n//}' file
```

Store all lines between the first instance of `<BR>INSTANCE NAME is : T0<BR>` to the end of the file in the hold space and do not print these lines immediately by deleting them. At the end of the file, swap to the hold space and using greed, remove everything up to and including the line containing `</table>` and print the remainder.